# Struct having pointer to member in C++, How to access it

Tags: c++, struct

OK here is my code. I have struct named employee and it has  a member char* name. How do I change the value of name?

```
struct employee {
    char* name;
    int age;
};

int main()
{
    struct employee james;
    james.age=12; // this line is fine 
    james.name = "james"; // this line is not working
    cout << james.name;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it works fine (?)

Comment: Use a `std::string`. And remove the `struct` from `struct employee james;`, its not needed in C++.

Comment: I must use char

Comment: If you want to assign the pointer name to a literal, try declaring the literal string as static char* sJames = "james";  then point .name to sJames in the same way you have done.

Comment: @Euler show your professor this: [CppCon 2015: Kate Gregory “Stop Teaching C"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnWhqhNdYyk)

Answer (score 5):

Use std::string instead of char* pointer, it will work fine

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct employee {
     std::string name; 
     int age; 
}; 
int main() { 
     employee james;
     james.age=12; 
    james.name = "james";

    std::cout << james.name; 

    return 0; 
}
```

Or
If you want to use char* pointer then use `const char* name`  it will work.

```
#include <iostream>
struct employee { 
     const char* name;
     int age;
 };

int main() {
     employee james; 
     james.age=12;
     james.name = "james"; 
     std::cout << james.name; 

return 0; 
}
```

Comment: you have to `#include <string>` at the top of the file for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

Any literal string value you enter into your source code (such as `"james"`) is by definition a `const char*` value, the `const` meaning it may not be altered at program runtime.  In your class the `name` member is declared to be of type `char*` which is not `const` and so *may* be altered at runtime.  Your compiler does not allow you to assign a `const char*` value to a variable of type `char*` to maintain the invariant that a value of type `const char*` may not be modified.  (The other way around is fine of course; you may assign a `char*` value to a variable of type `const char*`.

To fix this with the fewest characters, you must change `char* name` to `const char* name` in your `employee` struct definition.  However, I agree that the best thing to do is change it to a `std::string` member as @Hamza.S laid out in their answer.  The `std::string` class has an assignment operator that builds it out of a `const char*` value, so the line `james.name = "james"` in their answer essentially sets the `std::string` equal to the `const char*` value `"james"`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are keen on using char*, you could do something like this :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct employee {
    char *name;
    int age;
};

int main() {
    employee james;
    james.age=12;
    james.name = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);
    strcpy(james.name, "James");
    std::cout << james.name << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Or else you could use std::string in your struct like this :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct employee {
    std::string name; 
    int age;  
};

int main() {
    employee james;
    james.age=12; 
    james.name = "james";

    std::cout << james.name; 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `char*` example leaks memory

Answer (score -4):

You can try using strcpy

```
strcpy(james.name, "james");
```

Comment: `james.name` would have to point to allocated storage before you do that, otherwise you're writing to an indeterminate memory location